# Copy Script Trouble

Tags: copy, powershell-3.0

I've created a script that I found in other forums to copy a file from one server to another.  A bit of background here.  We have large PDF files being generated nightly and saved on a share at one site that need to be copied over to our corporate share.  These files are pretty sizable (anywhere between 25MB to as high as 65MB), so I can only copy these files off hours.  The source repository holds all the original files from the year, so I only want to copy the most recent files.  I created a script (or tried to at least) that copies only the most recent files from the SourceHost location to CorpHost share and set up a Task Schedule to run at 7:30pm.

The script kicks off and runs as scheduled, but nothing gets copied over.  I don't see any errors being generated from the task schedule and it appears to run as normal as the script returns a "not copying .pdf".  Originally, I though that maybe it was bypassing all the files because the generation date is outside the `$Max_days` range (-1), so I increased it to -2.  No luck.  Increased it again to -5 - no luck.  -10... nothing.

Here's the code sample:

```bsh
$RemotePath = "\\<CorpHost>\Shared\Packing_Slips\<Site>"
$SourcePath = "\\<SourceHost>\<Site>_packingslips"

$Max_days  = "-1"
$Curr_date = Get-Date

#Checking date and then copying file from RemotePath to LocalPath
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath))
{
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($Curr_date).AddDays($Max_days))
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $RemotePath 
    }
    else
    {
        "not copying $file"
    }
}
```

Comment: For incremental file transfers use [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145.aspx).

Comment: make a new dummy file and try , and try the same by running in console(without task)

Comment: Sorry, my scripting skills aren't that great.  Can I run "robocopy" in a PowerShell script?  And how do I modify the existing code to use robocopy?